# Python Turtle collision loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to build a simple game. The user control the turtle. When it touch the circle, the circle relocate and the player will be given one point. The program only run this bit one time, see comment in code. How do i make the program to always run it? I thought mainloop() did this.

```
def move_t2():
    t2.ht()
    rc_list = [-300, -250, -200, -150, -100, -50, 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300]
    r1 = random.choice(rc_list)
    r2 = random.choice(rc_list)
    t2.setpos(r1, r2)
    t2.st()

def more_points():
    t3_points.clear()
    new_points=points + 1
    if new_points >=0:
        t3_points.write("Points "+str(new_points),font=10)
  
# The program only run this part one time. I want it to loop.
if t.distance(t2) < 50:
    move_t2()
    more_points()


def mr():
    if t.xcor()<301:
        t.setheading(0)
        t.fd(50)
    else:
        t.setheading(180)
def ml():
    if t.xcor() > -301:
        t.setheading(180)
        t.fd(50)
    else:
        t.setheading(0)
def mu():
    if t.ycor() < 301:
        t.setheading(90)
        t.fd(50)
    else:
        t.setheading(270)
def md():
    if t.ycor() > -301:
        t.setheading(270)
        t.fd(50)
    else:
        t.setheading(90)

ts.onkey(mr,"Right")
ts.onkey(ml,"Left")
ts.onkey(mu,"Up")
ts.onkey(md,"Down")

ts.listen()
ts.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> The program only run this bit one time, see comment in code. How do i
> make the program to always run it? I thought mainloop() did this.

The code bit in question is at the top level and was only setup to be run once.  The `mainloop()` turns control over to the event handler so that keyboard keys, etc., can trigger events.  What needs to happen is that collision checking code needs to become a function and added to every keyboard event handler:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

POSITION_LIST = [-300, -250, -200, -150, -100, -50, 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300]

FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'normal')

def move_turtle(t):
    t.hideturtle()
    r1 = choice(POSITION_LIST)
    r2 = choice(POSITION_LIST)
    t.setpos(r1, r2)
    t.showturtle()

points = 0

def more_points():
    global points

    points += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write("Points: {}".format(points), align='center', font=FONT)

def mr():
    if t1.xcor() < 301:
        t1.setheading(0)
        t1.fd(25)
    else:
        t1.setheading(180)

    check_collision()

def ml():
    if t1.xcor() > -301:
        t1.setheading(180)
        t1.fd(25)
    else:
        t1.setheading(0)

    check_collision()

def mu():
    if t1.ycor() < 301:
        t1.setheading(90)
        t1.fd(25)
    else:
        t1.setheading(270)

    check_collision()

def md():
    if t1.ycor() > -301:
        t1.setheading(270)
        t1.fd(25)
    else:
        t1.setheading(90)

    check_collision()

def check_collision():
    if t1.distance(t2) < 20:
        move_turtle(t2)
        more_points()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(700, 700)

t1 = Turtle()
t1.shape('turtle')
t1.penup()
move_turtle(t1)

t2 = Turtle()
t2.shape('circle')
t2.penup()
move_turtle(t2)

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.penup()
pen.sety(-325)
pen.write("Points: {}".format(points), align='center', font=FONT)

screen.onkey(mr, "Right")
screen.onkey(ml, "Left")
screen.onkey(mu, "Up")
screen.onkey(md, "Down")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```